# Azure CLI Commands to add templates to workitems

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I have Product backlog item, I am able to see templates from Azure Board UI. I want to use Azure CLI commands to add templates to the product backlog item. I have query to create Backlog which is working fine but I am not getting how to add templates available to the backlog.

Comment: I am afraid azure cli does not have such a command to add templates. You can use Rest API to [create templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/templates/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1). Does this meet your needs?

Comment: Thank you. I have seen API approach but right now I am looking for Azure CLI commands. I have alternative approach of creating cards without templates. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no such Azure CLI command to add templates to workitems. If you would like that feature, please create a request for this feature [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/issues).